# Customisable products rule/restiction based

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, products

So I know how to create customisable products but what I want to do is create a customisable product with rules.

It's for an electrical website so for example the customer can create a 12 gang pdu with 6 UK sockets and 6 European sockets with a 16 Amp Fuse for example.

However I want there to be rules so customers cannot decide they want a 24 gang pdu with a 2 amp fuse in it.

How would I go about setting rules in place?

Comment: you can use product custom options concept of magneto to achieve this type of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean with "customizable product" but you tagged the question as [configurable-product](/questions/tagged/configurable-product), so if this is really a configurable product, it will be straightforward: for each combination you have to create a simple associated product. Create only simple products for the valid combinations and the customer will be unable to select invalid combinations.